# Link one KML placemark to another in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, kml

Using an embedded Google Map with API v3, I'm trying to create a hyperlink in one placemark's balloon that goes to another placemark in the same map. KML documentation says this is possible: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#featureanchor

The KML documentation doesn't state where you should put the id attribute. I've tried adding the id attribute within the placemark tag and the description/cdata tag. Despite where I put the anchor, the link (which displays correctly) causes the browser to reopen the page in another window.

```
<a href="#Albuquerque;balloonFlyto">Best Art Shows in the West</a>

<Placemark id="Albuquerque">
<name>...
```

Does this feature work in Google Earth, but not Google Maps? If so, is there any other way to link placemarks in Google Maps? Thanks!

Comment: You tagged your question google-maps-api-3, if you use that API and a third party KML parser to render the placemarks as native Google Maps objects, you can implement functionality that will do that.  It isn't built in.

Comment: Thanks for the help, geocodezip! Small world - I've been trying to learn from the examples on your site this morning. I'm new to working with maps. What third party KML parser would you recommend?

Comment: I personally would use [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) as I maintain it, but [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) by Lance Dyas should work too.  What does your KML look like?